# Is This Context-Per-Request Implementation Safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Let's say I have a helper class like this:

```
public static class RequestHelper {
    private const String DbContextKey = "DbContext";

    public static DbContext CurrentDbContext {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Items[DbContextKey] as DbContext; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Items[DbContextKey] = value; }
    }
}
```

And then in my `Global.asax.cs` I have:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest() {
    RequestHelper.CurrentDbContext = new DbContext("some_conn_string_name");
}
```

Is this design safe across all requests?  Will I run into any problems if I am always doing data access through `RequestHelper.CurrentDbContext`?

The reason I ask is that I've seen much more complicated implementations of context-per-request that rely on dependency injection.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious, and I'm afraid that I won't notice until I have a large enough number of users in the application.

Comment: It should fine if you dont have any longlife requests.

Comment: Don't forget to `Dispose` the context in `EndRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine, and in fact most of solutions you mention probably do something very similar under the hood. One problem is, that this code could be invoked also for static resources (js, css, etc..).

Another question is, if you will gain anything by doing this. If your system is very complicated, you might consider one of DI containers. If it isn't that complicated, it might be more maintainable to just create DbContext only when you need to.

Comment: What if I were to keep a `Lazy<DbContext>` in `Items[DbContextKey]` instead?